# performing two sided t.test for mean, median in a data set

Tags: r

I have a data set that contains the following columns:

```
STUDY   NSUB   MEAN   MEDIAN   SD
1       10     1.5    1.7      0.4
2       20     1.5    1.55     0.3
3       7      2.6    3        0.5
4       15     3      3.01     0.1
```

And so on.

I want to judge whether the mean and median are significantly different at significance level (alpha=0.05). This is so I can make a decision whether the data from each study were come from a normal or log-normal distribution. I thought of doing a two sided t-test. My hypothesis would be:

NULL: `H0: MEAN=MEDIAN`

Alternative: `HA: MEAN doesn't equal MEDIAN`

The standard error of the mean (SEM) can be calculated as `SD/NSUB` where NSUB is the number of subjects. The degree of freedom would be `NSUB-1`. The scenario I am presenting here is as if I am comparing two means that have the same standard deviation (SD).

Is there a way where I can do this automatically in R for the set of data that I have and have the result added to the data as `t.test.result` being TRUE/FALSE (significantly different/insignificantly different). Something close to this:

```
    STUDY   NSUB   MEAN   MEDIAN   SD     t.test.result
    1       10     1.5    1.7      0.4    RESULT1?
    2       20     1.5    1.55     0.3    RESULT2?
    3       7      2.6    3        0.5    RESULT3?
    4       15     3      3.01     0.1    RESULT4?
```

Comment: I realize that (in spite of the post notice saying otherwise) the exact duplicate doesn't have an answer. Nevertheless there's no point in having both.